# Makefile target with multiple dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a little script that compiles a markdown file into html, and inserts that into the body of a template, along with some stylesheets and javascript.  I've got a GNU makefile to accomplish this:

```
output.html: content.md compile.py style.css script.js
    python compile.py < $< > $@
```

When I run this I get the error:

> make: *** No rule to make target `style.css', needed by`output.html'.  Stop.

If I remove `compile.py`, `style.css`, and `script.js`, the target runs, but then it no longer depends on the files, so I can make a change in `style.css`, and it won't re-run the target.

All of these files are in the same directory:

```
my_project_directory/
    content.md
    compile.py
    style.css
    script.js
```

How do I declare all of these files as dependencies without causing errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've told make that `output.html` needs `style.css`, but the `style.css` file doesn't exist in the current directory and you haven't told make how to create it.  Specify the real location of `style.css` (and the other files) and the dependency will work.

Comment: oh, but the style.css file does exist in the current directory.  the locations given in the dependency list are correct relative to the Makefile's directory.

Comment: Your compilation script apparently knows how to find the files, but make doesn't.  There's no other reason for that error message.